# ** (RuntimeError) expected action/2 to return a Plug.Conn, all plugs must receive a connection (conn) and return a connection

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

```
def create_trans(conn, _params) do

  address = __MODULE__.get_add()
  card = __MODULE__.get_card()

  case Alpha.beta(card, [billing_address: address]) do
    {:ok, result}     -> render conn,"purchase.json",%{purchase: result}
    {:error, reason}  -> render conn,"purchase.json",%{purchase: reason} 
  end

end
```

The above code gives me the below error, am i missing anything.

> ** (RuntimeError) expected action/2 to return a Plug.Conn, all plugs must receive a connection (conn) and return a connection

Comment: It looks like you didn't cover every possibilites - try to do also the case for `_` at the end of this `case`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe provide more informations what `Alpha.beta/2` should return. Generally your error points that **not every scenario is covered** in your `case` block. Consider using as a last scenario `_`, which will match the rest.

Also you could simply make this code more readable and DRY if you assign result of the `Alpha.beta/2` to the variable and then render the result instead of using `case`, if you basically do the same in both of these scenarios.

```
{_, result} = Alpha.beta(card, [billing_address: address)
render(conn, "purchase.json", %{purchase: result}
```

But in this case you have to be **100%** sure that this `Alpha.beta/2` returns a tuple, which matches in pattern matching above and according to your issue, it's not so sure.